# Opening mongoose connection using router.use in express 4.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am transistioning my code from `monk` to `mongoose`.
I have opened a connection to `mongodb` using `router` middleware:

```
//use router middleware to connect to mongodb using mongoose
router.use(function(req,res,next){
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/takenote');

  //take a look here to figure out how to handle mongoose connection:
  //http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/
  mongoose.connection.on('error',function(err){
    if(err)
      console.error(err);
  });
  mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){
    console.log('connection established');
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',function(){
    console.log('Disconnected from mongo db');
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('SIGINT',function(){
    //sigint represents the termination of the app
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
      console.log("Connection to mongo db has been closed because the app terminated");
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
  next();
});
```

I use the `routes` defined here to call `mongoose` methods:

```
router.get('/main',function(req,res){
   var locals={};
   locals.title="TakeNote:An easy to use note taking app for web and hopefully mobile";
   locals.sidebar={};
   locals.sidebar.items=[];
   locals.notebook={};
   locals.notebook.notes=[];

   notebook
   .find()
   .populate('notes')
   .exec(function(err,docs){
      _(docs).forEach(function(notebook){
          locals.sidebar.items.push(notebook.title);
          locals.notebook.notes=notebook.notes;
          res.render('main',locals);    
     });
  });   
});
```

I get an error when calling any of the routes:

```
  { [Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.] state: 1 }
```

How can I solve this issue?Is placing the `mongoose` connection in the `router` middleware bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. Open the `mongoose` connection during your app's startup code instead.  It's a connection pool that's intended to be shared by all requests and left open during the life of your app.